# handlebars get index for loop

Tags: backbone.js, handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

I have an helper written in backbone and handlebars and I need to get index of the for loop inside.

This is my helper

```
 Handlebars.registerHelper('for', function(from, to, incr, block) {
        var accum = '';
        for(var i = from; i < to; i += incr)
            accum += block.fn(i);
        return accum;
    });
```

And this is my template:

```
{{#each rows}}
    <div class="row">
        {{#for 0 10 1}}
            <div class="edit-column" data-id="{{@index}}">
            </div>
        {{/for}}
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

I woudl like that `{{@index}}` print the index of the for loop, now it prints the counter of `{{#each rows}}` loop

How can I get index of the for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking to [inject private variables](http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html#hash-arguments) into your templates :

> Block helpers can also inject private variables into their child
>   templates. This can be useful to add extra information that is not in
>   the original context data.
>
> For example, when iterating over a list, you may provide the current
>   index as a private variable.

You just have to provide a data entry in the options you pass to your block function (and ensure the coherence of the child data object with [`Handlebars.createFrame`](http://handlebarsjs.com/reference.html#base-createFrame))

A modified helper exposing an `@index` key:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('for', function(from, to, incr, block) {
    var data;

    if (block.data) {
        data = Handlebars.createFrame(block.data);
    }

    var accum = '';
    for(var i = from; i < to; i += incr) {
        if (data) {
          data.index = i;
        }
        accum += block.fn(i, {data: data});
    }
    return accum;
});
```

and a demo

```js
Handlebars.registerHelper('for', function(from, to, incr, block) {
    var data;

    if (block.data) {
        data = Handlebars.createFrame(block.data);
    }


    var accum = '';
    for(var i = from; i < to; i += incr) {
        if (data) {
          data.index = i;
        }
        accum += block.fn(i, {data: data});
    }
    return accum;
});

var tpl = Handlebars.compile($('#rows').html());
$('body').append(tpl({
    rows: [1, 2]
}));
```

```css
.edit-column {padding-left: 10px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.5/handlebars.min.js"></script>

<script type='text/template' id='rows'>
{{#each rows}}
    <div class="row">{{@index}}
        {{#for 0 3 1}}
            <div class="edit-column">{{@../index}}:{{@index}}</div>
        {{/for}}
    </div>
{{/each}}
</script>
```

Comment: You may also benefit from learning more about how partials and helpers can work together as well: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/handlebars-js-part-2-partials-and-helpers